# Open PDF and save specific pages as new PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, sendkeys

I have a PDF that I need to mail out each day. I have a macro set up in my excel file that updates a table of data that goes in the body of the email and then it opens up this PDF file and saves 4 pages as a PDF and attaches it to the email that I send.

The problem is, sendkeys really isn't that reliable and I'd like to use something else or have it just silently open and save those specific pages as a new pdf in my temp folder. Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Print_All_PDF_Files_in_Folder()
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\temp\S4 Region.pdf"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Dim folder As String
    Dim PDFfilename As String
    folder = "location of pdf"    'CHANGE AS REQUIRED
    If Right(folder, 1) <> "\" Then folder = folder & "\"
        PDFfilename = Dir(folder & "S4 Reg" & "*.pdf", vbNormal)
    While Len(PDFfilename) <> 0
        Print_PDF folder & PDFfilename
        PDFfilename = Dir()  ' Get next matching file
    Wend
    Call ClosePDF
End Sub

Private Sub Print_PDF(sPDFfile As String)
    Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe /p " & Chr(34) & sPDFfile & Chr(34)
    SendKeys "p"
    SendKeys "%g"
    SendKeys "{tab}"
    SendKeys "5,9,14,15"
    SendKeys "%r"
    SendKeys "{down 2}"
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now)
    SendKeys "{enter}"
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
    SendKeys "{tab 6}"
    SendKeys "{enter}"
    SendKeys "C:\temp"
    SendKeys "%s"
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now)
End Sub

Sub ClosePDF()
    Dim Process As Object, intError As Integer
    For Each Process In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='AcroRd32.exe'")
         intError = Process.Terminate   'Terminates a process and all of its threads.
         If intError <> 0 Then Exit For 'Return value is 0 for success. Any other number is an error.
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> silently open and save those specific pages as a new pdf in my temp folder.

You need to use the [Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat) method which is used to publish a workbook to either the PDF or XPS format. Pay attention to the following parameters:

- `From` - The number of the page at which to start publishing. If this argument is omitted, publishing starts at the beginning.
- `To` - The number of the last page to publish. If this argument is omitted, publishing ends with the last page.
- `OpenAfterPublish` - If set to `True`, displays the file in the viewer after it is published. If set to `False`, the file is published but not displayed.

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF FileName:="sales.pdf" Quality:=xlQualityStandard From:=2 To:=4 OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene for the response. Unfortunately, my goal is to open a PDF file that has about 25 page and then save just 4 pages of that PDF into a new PDF in my temp folder. Not needing to save my current sheet as a PDF.